# How do pass arguments to boost asio async_accept

Tags: c++, boost, bind, boost-asio, stdbind

I have one problem.

I'm developing chat server, using boost::asio.

and Here,

```
void CServerSocket::StartAccept(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor &acceptor)
{
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(acceptor.get_io_service()));

    acceptor.async_accept(*socket, std::bind(&CServerSocket::OnAccept, boost::asio::placeholders::error, socket,
        std::ref(acceptor)));
}

void CServerSocket::OnAccept(const boost::system::error_code &error, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, 
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor &acceptor)
{
    if (error)
    {
        CLogManager::WriteLog((boost::format("Accept error! : %1%") % error.message()).str().c_str());
        return;
    }

    m_SocketList.push_back(std::make_shared<CConnectionSocket>(this, socket));

    StartAccept(acceptor);
}
```

At std::bind, there are an error occurred.

"Error c2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments"

What should i do?

thanks.

Comment: one error is you forgot the instance to bind with. you need a **this** as second parameter. `std::bind(&CServerSocket::OnAccept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, socket, std::ref(acceptor))`

Comment: I've already tried. but, there is an another error occurred. Error 1 error C2664: '_Rx std::_Pmf_wrap<_Pmf_t,_Rx,_Farg0,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>::operator ()<PengChat::CServerSocket*>(const _Wrapper &,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t) const' : cannot cast 'boost::arg<I>' to 'const boost::system::error_code &'. c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional 1152

Comment: umm thats the second error, i think... you cannot use std::bind with std::shared_ptr but boost::asio::placeholders. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9536984/1810087)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `std::bind`, replace `boost::asio::placeholders::error` with `std::placeholders::_1`.

Answer (score -1):

An accept handler may only take an error code as a parameter, see: [AcceptHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html).

I recommend making `acceptor` a member of `CServerSocket` then changing the call to `async_accept`
 to:

```
acceptor.async_accept(*socket, std::bind(&CServerSocket::OnAccept, this,
                                         std::placeholders::_1));
```

and accessing `acceptor` within the `OnAccept` member function.

Comment: That's incorrect. See [std::bind documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistake @Igor. I've amended my answer to use a `std::placeholder` instead of the `boost::placeholder` from the asio documentation.

Comment: You answer still implies that it's impossible (or incorrect) to pass to `CServerSocket::OnAccept` extra parameters - which is incorrect as well.