# Can't use asio::placeholders::error in non-Boost version of Asio

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to use the non Boost version of Asio in a project. I'm writing a callback to `stream_protocol::acceptor::async_accept`. The signature requires `asio::placeholders::error` to be passed but when I do so, I get the following error:

`error: no member named 'error' in namespace 'asio::placeholders'`

Following the source, I can see error is there but of type `undefined`, which is new to me. Am I missing something? Am I supposed to do some sort of pre-processing of the libraries?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In short, use `std::placeholders::_1` instead of `asio::placeholders:error`.

---

Asio only supports the convenient placeholder variables when using Boost.Bind.  The `error` placeholder [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/placeholders__error.html) states:

> An argument placeholder, for use with **`boost::bind()`**, ...

When using `std::bind()` to create handlers, one needs to use `std::bind`'s placeholders.   The [`async_accept()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload2.html) operation accepts a handler that meets the [AcceptHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html) type requirements:

> An accept handler must meet the requirements for a handler. A value `h` of an accept handler class should work correctly in the expression `h(ec)`, where `ec` is an lvalue of type `const error_code`.

When creating a functor with `std::bind()` to function as a AcceptHandler, if one wishes to obtain the `error_code` argument, then use `std::placeholders::_1`:

```cpp
void handle_accept(const std::error_code&);

acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, std::bind(&handle_accept,
  std::placeholders::_1 /* error_code */));
```

---

Here is a complete minimal example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94f5c568e955f444) using `std::bind()`.  Note that coliru does not appear to have an Asio standalone version available, but the example should suffice:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error_code)
{
  std::cout << "handle_accept: " << error_code.message() << std::endl;
}

void noop() {}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // Connect client and server sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, std::bind(&handle_accept,
    std::placeholders::_1 /* error_code */));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), std::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();
}
```

Output:

```
handle_accept: Success
```

Optionally, if one wishes for a bit more verbosity, then named placeholders could be used:

```cpp
namespace asio_placeholders
{
  auto error = std::placeholders::_1;
}

// ...

acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, std::bind(&handle_accept,
  asio_placeholders::error));
```

---

The `unspecified` type observed in the source code is only used when generating documentation, as shown in this [code](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/asio-1-10-4/asio/include/asio/placeholders.hpp#L29-L51):

```cpp
#if defined(GENERATING_DOCUMENTATION)

/// An argument placeholder, for use with boost::bind(), that corresponds to
/// the error argument of a handler for any of the asynchronous functions.
unspecified error;

// ...

#elseif
```

Comment: Alternatively when using Boost.Bind with non-boost Asio you have to define `ASIO_HAS_BOOST_BIND` to get the convenience placeholders.