# Boost, ASIO - how are they connected and how can I use ASIO standalone

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, asio

I am new to ASIO and Boost and I'm quite confused. The goal is to use ASIO standalone and distribute it with my CMake project. My naive approach  was [downloading](https://think-async.com/Asio/) ASIO(non Boost) and coping the files into my CMake project, add a few include directories to it and follow the Asio(non Boost) [examples](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.24.0/doc/asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html). First thing I see there, the example happily includes headers ("boost/array.hpp", "boost/bind/bind.hpp" and "shared_ptr.hpp")from a boost folder which doesn't even exist in the downloaded ASIO version. Not that I expected it, it's called non-Boost-Asio for a reason I thought. All of this makes me believe I am completely misunderstanding this whole Boost/ASIO thing, can anyone guide me into the right direction, Google didn't :)

Comment: here https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioStandalone.html it says that it is only standalone with C++11 or later. What C++ standard are you compiling against?

Comment: C++17. I can use it standalone, that's not the problem. I am just wondering why the ASIO (non boost) examples use boost.

Comment: where did you read that it is "ASIO (non boost)" ? I only see that its called ASIO and the link I posted. It has boost dependencies, unless compiled as C++11 or later, then it is standalone. I guess the examples are old, or maintained like that because it is simpler to remove the includes rather than to add them

Comment: Here: https://think-async.com/Asio/index.html

Comment: and there: https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio.html

Comment: ok now I see it. Here they explain the difference between the two flavours: https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio.html. Anyhow the example uses other stuff from boost. Did you try to remove/replace it and compile the example without boost?

Comment: Instead of using boost library you can use equivalent version from C++ standard library. `std::bind`, `std::array` and `std::shared_ptr`. Take a look at this post while using `std::bind` instead of `boost::bind`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486347/cant-use-asioplaceholderserror-in-non-boost-version-of-asio

Comment: OK, it works. Amir is right, I just replaced everything boost specific in the example with the equivalant standard lib functionality and it works fine. The example is misleading, it shoudn't even be there I think :)